# How can I animate particles movements in R

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2

I want to animate the position of many particles at same time

Supose we have :

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
    y = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1),
    particle = c(1,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,2,1),
    time = 1:10 )
```

that means: particle 1, in time 1, is in position (x=1, y=2)
Then goes to position (x=2, y=3) in time 2, etc.

particle 2 appears in time 3 in position (x=3, y=4) and moves in time 9 to other position.

etc.

I have try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y), show.legend=FALSE)  +  
    geom_point() +
    transition_states(time)
```

But the animation only shows only one particle at same time.

How can I animate all particles ( in the example, the three particles must be visible all the time)

thkx.

bt.

Comment: Where are particles 2 and 3 at time 1? *"the three particles must be visible all the time"*

Comment: Yes, you can't animate the position of many particles at the same time because for each timepoint there is only one particle.

Comment: they are not visible at time 1. They appear later.  But after that , they must be visible all the time

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep all the particles visible, you have to create rows for each particle at each timepoint (you can leave out the rows before particle 2 and 3 appear). Doing this with the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

expanded = df %>%
    # Create rows for each combination of particle and time
    complete(particle, time) %>%
    group_by(particle) %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    # Fill missing x and y with the current position, up to
    #   the next change for that particle
    fill(x, y, .direction = "down")

# Make particle a factor
ggplot(expanded, aes(x, y, colour = factor(particle)))  +  
    geom_point() +
    transition_states(time)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help

I arrived to this solution:

```
p<- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) 
for (i in 1:3) p<- p + geom_label(data = subset(df,particle ==paste(i)), aes(x = x, y = y,label = particle), size =1, color = i) 
p<-p+labs(title = "{frame_time}") +
transition_components(time) 
animate(p, fps = 10)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCOSl.gif)